# Trouble to get correct value within php echo in Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$id = "123";
```

On book.php, passing $id to external jquery-book.php.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var id = '<?php echo $id; ?>';
</script>    

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-book.php"></script>
```

On jquery-book.php, i have these codes.:

```
<?php
  function get_book($id) {  
    return ...
  }
?>

$(document).ready(function(){
  var book_id = '<?php echo get_book(' + id + '); ?>'; //PROBLEM!!!
  $('#main').html(book_id);
});
```

If i alert(id);, i can get "123". But from above code, i get " + id + ", not "123".

Why???

Comment: Javascript runs on the client, php on the server. You need ajax to solve your problem.

Comment: Where did you put the alert?

Comment: No he didn't. richard is trying to pass a javascript variable into a PHP function, the best way to resolve that is by using AJAX.

Comment: @marteljn Inside $(document).ready(function(){ alert(id); });

Comment: Do you have to use script tags around the + id + because its in the php tags

Comment: how will u write client side script in server side.... :):)..."<?php echo  " + myname + "?>".. there is no way u can do this.. if this was possible then i think there will be no such thing called AJAX

Comment: Ah, crap I misread it. I need more freaking coffee!

Comment: @lanO.S Do you mean like this: get_book(<script>' + id + '</script>) ??

Comment: That's not the problem. He is not trying to access the PHP variable `$id` there, but the JS variable `id` (which is accessible by JS at that point). The problem is that while you can mix PHP into JS statements, you cannot mix JS into PHP statements the way your're trying here.

Comment: what is actually returned by get_book() function ?? HTML or some varaible

Comment: @bipen e.g: return "Book id is:".$id;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Book.php**

```
<?php

$id = "123";

include_once "jquery-book.php";

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     var id = '<?php echo $id; ?>';
    </script>    

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var book_id = '<?php echo get_book($id); ?>'; //PROBLEM SOLVED!!!
      alert(book_id);
      $('#main').html(book_id);
    });
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**jquery-book.php**

```
<?php
  function get_book($id) {  
    return $id . '-success';
  }
?>
```

Not satisfied still? Then please use Ajax-PHP combination.  http://openenergymonitor.org/emon/node/107